# How to restrict log4j console appender to log only on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, consoleappender

Working in both development and deployment environment,
I want my log4j.properties to have include console appender, so I could view log messages when I develop. However when I deploy the application, I prefer to disable the console appender.

Is there a filter I can add on the console appender to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Deploy the application with a different log4j config file, that's why it's an external file.

Comment: I was hoping to a more elegant method. e.g. have log4J use console appender only on localhost...
Your solution requires me to have my build (maven) augmented with profiles

Comment: @Dudi yeah, profiles can be a pain. But there is fiddling to do when you move an application from development to production, and logging config is always going to be one of them.